# Improper parsing of strings

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to convert ansi color codes from console output into HTML. I have a found a script to do this but I cant seem to make it parse the strings inside node js. I have tried to JSON.stringify it to also include special chars but its not working.

```
forever list
[32minfo[39m:    Forever processes running
[90mscript[39m           [37mforever[39m [37mpid[39m  [37mid[39m
[90mdata[39m:    [37m   [39m  [37muid[39m  [90mcommand[39m
```

I get output like this back from ssh2shell in node js. I have a script:
https://github.com/pixelb/scripts/blob/master/scripts/ansi2html.sh

This is supposed to convert the above to html and add the appropriate color codes. It works fine with normal terminal output for example:

```
npm install --color=always | ansi2html.sh > npminstall.html
```

This is the raw output on the linux machine piped to a file. It seems the JS strings are missing these escapes when they are shown in console.log but they are also missing newlines there. Perhaps its because im concatenating them directly into the string and its removing special chars?

```
total 24
-rwxr-xr-x 1 admin admin 17002 May 13 02:52 ^[[0m^[[38;5;34mansi2html.sh^[[0m
drwxr-xr-x 4 admin admin  4096 May 13 00:00 ^[[38;5;27mgit^[[0m
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin     0 May 13 02:57 ls.html
```

Hopefully some of this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get the ANSI strings from? A file? stdin? Hardcoded in the code?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of filters that SSH2shell applies to the output from commands. The first removes non-standard ASCII from the response and then the colour formatting codes are removed.

In v1.6.0 I have added pipe()/unpipe(), the events for both and exposed the stream.on('data', function(data){}) event so you can access the stream output directly without SSH2shell interacting with it in any way.
This should resolve the problem of not getting the right output from SSH2shell by giving you access to the raw data.

```
var fs = require('fs')

var host = {
  server:             {     
    host:         mydomain.com,
    port:         22,
    userName:     user,
    password:     password:)
  },
  commands:           [
    "`Test session text message: passed`",
    "msg:console test notification: passed",
    "ls -la"
  ],

}
//until npm published use the cloned dir path.
var SSH2Shell = require ('ssh2shell')

//run the commands in the shell session
var SSH = new SSH2Shell(host),
    callback = function( sessionText ){
          console.log ( "-----Callback session text:\n" + sessionText);
          console.log ( "-----Callback end" );
      },
    firstLog = fs.createWriteStream('first.log'),
    secondLog = fs.createWriteStream('second.log'),
    buffer = ""

//multiple pipes can be added but they wont be bound to the stream until the connection is established    
SSH.pipe(firstLog).pipe(secondLog);    

SSH.on('data', function(data){
    //do something with the data chunk
    console.log(data)
})

SSH.connect(callback)
```

Answer (score 0):

tried this ?

https://github.com/hughsk/ansi-html-stream

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn
  , ansi = require('ansi-html-stream')
  , fs = require('fs')

var npm = spawn('npm', ['install', 'browserify', '--color', 'always'], {
    cwd: process.cwd()
})

var stream = ansi({ chunked: false })
  , file = fs.createWriteStream('browserify.html', 'utf8')

npm.stdout.pipe(stream)
npm.stderr.pipe(stream)

stream.pipe(file, { end: false })

stream.once('end', function() {
  file.end('</pre>\n')
})

file.write('<pre>\n');
```